# C factoring a number into prime factors

Tags: c++, math, prime-factoring

I wrote a program that factors numbers into its prime factors, then stores them in a vector, and lastly asks whether to verify the result by multiplying them out.

It works this way: ask for a number (`num` in the code), and divide it by 2 and up.

If it finds a number (the `divisor` in the code) whose modulo (when `num` mod `divisor`) is zero, store that divisor into a vector, and reduce `num` by dividing it by the `divisor` and store it into `temp`, and reset the divisor to 1 (and the last statement in the `while` loop will increment it to 2. If no such number is found, `divisor` increases until it is greater or equal to `num`. This process continues until `divisor` is greater than `num`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //num=the number of interest
    //divisor=the number dividing the number of interest each time
    unsigned long  divisor=2, num, temp ; //num=13699293826d
    char c;

    vector<unsigned long> divisors;
    cout<<"Enter a number: "<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    //temp stores the number that is reduced each time
    temp=num;

    while(divisor<=num)
    {
        if(temp%divisor==0)
        {
             temp=temp/divisor;
             divisors.push_back(divisor);
             cout<<"one "<<divisor<<endl;
             cout<<"the number of interest is now"<<temp<<endl;
             divisor=1;
        }
        if(divisor==temp&&temp!=1)
        {
            cout<<"two " << divisor<<endl;
            divisors.push_back(divisor);
        }

        divisor++;
    }

    if(divisors[0]==num)
    {
        cout<<"The number: "<<num<<" is prime. ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Its proper divisors are: ";
        for(unsigned int count=0; count<divisors.size(); count++ )
        {
            cout<<divisors[count]<<"\t";
        }
    }

    cout<<"Print out the multiplication? Press 'Y' or 'N'."<<endl;
    cin>>c;

    if(c=='Y'||c=='y')
    {
        for(unsigned int count=0; count<divisors.size(); count++)
        {
            temp*=divisors[count];
            cout<<temp<<"\t";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have printed some debug `cout` statements.

The problem I have with it is this: when the number is sufficiently large, the debug 
statement "the number of interest is now", has the number 1 following it.
Then, the program crashes.

What is wrong with the code?

Thanks.

---

And yes, I am running it on 64 bits.

A sample program output:

```
    Enter a number: 
    13699293826
    one 3
    the number of interest is now: 1431655765
    one 5
    the number of interest is now: 286331153
    one 17
    the number of interest is now: 16843009
    one 257
    the number of interest is now: 65537
    one 65537
    the number of interest is now: 1
```

And then the program crashes.

I also noticed that the first "prime factor" of 3 is incorrect, because 13699293826 divided by 3 is 4562761275.333333333333333.....

edit # 2------------------------------------------

```
    temp 65537, divisor 62287

    ..............omitted output

    temp 65537, divisor 65530
    temp 65537, divisor 65531
    temp 65537, divisor 65532
    temp 65537, divisor 65533
    temp 65537, divisor 65534
    temp 65537, divisor 65535
    temp 65537, divisor 65536
    temp 65537, divisor 65537
    one 65537
    the number of interest is now: 1
    Its proper divisors are: 3  5   17  257 65537   Print out the                 multiplication? Press 'Y' or 'N'.
```

And then the program stops responding, and it does not work when I press "y" and enter.

Also, the number multiplied are not correct; the result is 4294967295... after googling, it says it is "the highest number you can get using 32 bits (BInary digiTS)". But on my PC, it says the operating system is 64 bit.

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit platform?

Comment: Why don't you add a `cout << "temp " << temp << ", divisor " << divisor << '\n';` at the top of the `if(temp%divisor==0)` statement block... then you can see what numbers are being divided and whether the `temp` result makes sense. It'd be good to edit your question to include the output leading up to the crash.  You could also watch execution in an interactive debugger and see if the variables contain the values you expect, and exactly which line crashes.

Comment: when asking questions on SO about errors, you should always include full error message.

Comment: **use `unsigned long long`** everywhere in your whole program. `unsigned long` is still 32 bits. your long number got truncated, and became just `1431655765 * 3 = 4294967295 = 2^32 - 1`. It's right there in your output. Its factorization is indeed `3,5,17,257,65537`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the message "the number of interest is now 1" it means that `temp == 1` now. You should have stopped at this point but you continue, because your loop erroneously compares `divisor` with `num`, whereas it should be comparing it with `temp`.

So now `temp == 1` and `divisor == 2`, and you will loop until the `unsigned long divisor` wraps around to 0. At which point your check `if(temp%divisor==0)` causes division by zero. I'd expect this to happen for any input.

---

You shouldn't reset the `divisor`, and your loop condition is wrong. Your loop should be like this:

```
while( divisor*divisor <= temp)
{
    if(temp%divisor==0)
    {
         temp=temp/divisor;
         divisors.push_back(divisor);
         cout<<"one "<<divisor<<endl;
         cout<<"the number of interest is now"<<temp<<endl;
         ///// divisor=1;
    }
    /* ------ if(divisor==temp&&temp!=1)
    {
        cout<<"two " << divisor<<endl;
        divisors.push_back(divisor);
    } ------- */
    else ////////
        divisor++;
}
if( temp > 1)
{
    divisors.push_back( temp );
    temp = 1;  // <<-------------- ADD THIS
}
```

Comment: However, when I use this loop condition, the output is off:
Enter a number: 
23425
one 5
the number of interest is now4685
one 5
the number of interest is now937
Its proper divisors are: 5 5 937 Print out the multiplication? Press 'Y' or 'N'.
y
4685 23425 21949225

Whereas the output should be : 
Enter a number: 
23425
one 5
the number of interest is now4685
one 5
the number of interest is now937
one 937
the number of interest is now1
Its proper divisors are: 5 5 937 Print out the multiplication? Press 'Y' or 'N'.
y
5 25 23425

Comment: both outputs you cite mean exactly the same thing: `23425 = 5*5*937`.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I have modified the loop condition to if(temp!=1)

Comment: `if(temp!=1)` is **wrong**. It will work way too long. it will make your program very slow.

Comment: I do have a little more question though. How did you come up with (divisor * divisor <= temp) condition?

Comment: that's just very well known part of the algorithm of testing for primality. if `a*b=n` and `a <= b`, then `a <= sqrt(n)` or `a*a <= n`. No need to test the bigger `b` - we're guaranteed to hit the smaller `a` earlier. And if we didn't, then `n` is surely prime. Here with factorization, when we find `a` we divide it out of `n`, and so are left with `b`. and we continue with `temp = b`. and if it is prime, we stop at *its* square root. Hence if in the end `temp>1`, it is the last divisor.